# Ordering algorithms from slowest to fastest

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Given functions:

1. $2^{\lg n} \lg n$
2. $2^{1000}$
3. $\lg \lg n$
4. $n / 1000$
5. $2^{2^{n}}$
6. $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$
7. $n^{0.0001}$
8. $\ln \left(\ln ^{2} n\right)$
9. $4^{n}$
10. $\lg ^{100} n$
11. $n \lg n$
12. $n \log _{4} n$

Is my ordering by growth rate correct (I am new to this)? Here $\lg n$ means $log_{2}$.

(a) $2^{1000}$ (It's a constant.)

(b) $\lg \lg n$ (Log of log grows extremely slowly.)

(c) $\ln \left(\ln ^{2} n\right)$ (Natural log of a square log.)

(d) $\lg ^{100} n$ (A power of log still grows slower than polynomial functions.)

(e) $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ (Root functions are sub-linear but grow faster than logarithmic functions.)

(f) $n / 1000$, $n \log _{4} n$ (Both are linear functions. The base-4 log is essentially a constant multiplier.)

(g) $n^{0.0001}$ (Tiny power, but it's still a polynomial.)

(h) $2^{\lg n} \lg n$, $n \lg n$ ($n$ times log $n$ grows faster than any polynomial but slower than exponentials.)

(i) $4^{n}$ (An exponential function.)

(j) $2^{2^{n}}$ (A double-exponential. It grows extremely fast.)

The functions in the same line (e.g., $n / 1000$ and $n \log _{4} n$) are in the same group, meaning their growth rates are equivalent and are represented by the $\Theta$ notation.

Comment: You might want to explain what your definition of growth rate is. For example, I don't see any sense in which $2^{1000}$ "grows", yet it is (h) on your list, suggesting it is supposed to grow faster than $n/1000$ but slower than $4^n$.

Comment: This is more than one question. If you have doubts about any single particular part of your ordering, [edit] the question to ask about that. Show us why you think what you have done is correct, and why you are unsure.

Comment: When you post questions, remember your readers may know a lot of mathematics, but may use different terms than you do, so it's very helpful to briefly give the definitions of the main notions you are using. It can also be useful to give examples of your reasoning rather than just say "the ordering is this", since that way a reader can tell, if they get a different answer, whether the issue is a conceptual one, or a computational one.

Comment: @krm2233 Thanks for the clarification. Oh yeah, I just looked now and it's a mistake. $2^{1000}$ should be first in the order then. By ordering all these functions by order of growth from slowest to fastest, I mean finding an arrangement $f_{1}(n), f_{2}(n), \ldots, f_{12}(n)$ of these functions such that $f_{1}=O\left(f_{2}(n)\right), f_{2}=O\left(f_{3}(n)\right), \ldots, f_{11}=O\left(f_{12}(n)\right)$. And partitioning into groups such that two functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are in the same group if and only if $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: @EthanBolker  I have edited the answer to add reasoning/logic. Let me know if you think it seems okay.

Comment: I am confused, isn't $\log ( \log^2 n ) = 2 \log \log n$. How do you say this "grows faster" or "slower" than $\log \log n$?

Comment: Also $\log_4 n$ is a constant multiplier? What? That is definitely not true. In particular, you have $n \log_4 n = \Theta( n \mathrm{lg}~n)$.

Comment: @DrewBrady Thanks for the answer. Oh I see, $n \log_4 n = \Theta (n \log n)$ makes sense. Would $\log(\log^2 n) = 2\log \log n$ grow at the same rate as $\ln \ln n$ (not $\log \log n$)?

Comment: There are errors here - too many to deal with in comments. Redo your work. Look at the limits of ratios, not just words like "grows faster" and "polynomial". Then ask about doubts one at a time. Voting to close the question as is.

Comment: Yes, since $\ln \ln n = \ln (c \log n) = \ln c+ \ln \log n = \ln c + c \log \log n$, where $c$ is the change of base.

Comment: $\frac{n \log_4 n}{n/1000} \to \infty$, so your "essentially constant multiplier" tends to infinity....